# An alternative Lyapunov-like instability proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Let $\gamma$ and $\omega$ be two positive real numbers. Consider the following 1-dimensional linear time-varying system
$$
\dot{x}(t)=\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma)-\cos(\omega t) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4\cos^2(\omega t) +(1-\gamma)^2}\right)}_{=:a(t)}x(t), \quad x(0)\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

By direct computation of the solution of the above differential equation, it is easy to check that, *for $\gamma$ sufficiently small*, the origin of the above system is an **unstable** equilibrium point.

However, I'd like to prove instability of the origin via a Lyapunov approach. More precisely, *supposing that $\gamma$ is sufficiently small*, I'd like to find a function $v(x,t):=q(t)x(t)^2$ such that

1. The norm of $q(t)$ is bounded in $t$, i.e. $\|q(t)\|\le k$, $k>0$, for all $t\ge 0$;
2. The derivative of $v(x,t)$ along the trajectories of the system is strictly negative for all $t$, that is $2a(t)q(t)+\dot{q}(t)<0$ for all $t$;
3. There exists (at least) a $\bar{t}>0$ such that $q(\bar{t})<0$.

So my question is:

> Is it actually possible to find such a Lyapunov function $v(x,t)$?

I made several attempts but no one worked. So every comment/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think that pp. 253-256 in Wofgang Hahn's [Stability of Motion](https://books.google.com/books/about/Stability_of_Motion_W_Hahn.html?id=IsKAngEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) could be of some help.

Comment: @user539887: thanks for the ref! After a quick look at it, it seems to me the outlined constructive procedure yields a non-quadratic Lyapunov function...unfortunately, I was looking for a quadratic one